# Can't set session.save_handler to memcache

Tags: nginx, php, memcache

NGINX + PHP-FPM 5.7.12

I'm trying to set my session handler to memcache, so I installed the module php-memcache, opened /etc/php.ini and changed the following lines:

```
session.save_handler = memcache
session.save_path = "tcp://MEMCACHESERVERIP:11211?persistent=1&weight=1&timeout=1&retry_interval=15"
```

So I restart nginx, php-fpm, open a page with phpinfo(); and at the session section I see session.save_handler = files at the Master and Local Value

Then I run the command at the ssh
    php-fpm -i | grep session.save
and I receive
    session.save_handler => memcache => memcache
    session.save_path => tcp://MEMCACHESERVERIP:11211?persistent=1&weight=1&timeout=1&retry_interval=15 => tcp://MEMCACHESERVERIP:11211?persistent=1&weight=1&timeout=1&retry_interval=15

Then my last option is to go to the nginx error log see if there is any error and I see PHP trying to save the session in the disk

does anyone know what should I do? Definally php is not saving my sessions at the memcache server.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution
for PHP-FPM you should set session.save parameters at /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf, not at /etc/php.ini